# C# tcp client (ASCII)

Tags: c#, tcp, client, ascii

I'm trying to read a server using Tcp Client. To read the server you need to send commands.

**Commands (ASCII communication):**

**Octet 001:** SOH;
**Octet 002:** Access code:
"0" - Read
"1" - Demand
"2" - Update
**Octet 003:** STX;
**Octet 004-135:** Command for convencional communication server/reader, converted nibble to nibble to ASCII code including CRC;
**Octet 136:** ETX;
**Octet 137:** LRC;

**Simple response:**

**Octet 001:** STX;
**Octet 002-517:** Simple response for convencional communication server/reader, converted nibble to nibble to ASCII code including CRC;
**Octet 518:** ETX;
**Octet 519:** LRC;

***My Tcp Client code:***

```
static void Connect(String server, String message)
        {
            

            try
            {                
                // Create a TcpClient.
                // Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer
                // connected to the same address as specified by the server, port
                // combination.
                Int32 port = 2180;
                
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);                
                // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
                Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

                // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
                //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();

                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                
                // Send the message to the connected TcpServer.
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                
                Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);

                // Receive the TcpServer.response.

                // Buffer to store the response bytes.
                //data = new Byte[256];
                data = new Byte[9];

                // String to store the response ASCII representation.
                String responseData = String.Empty;

                // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.                
                Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);                
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);

                // Close everything.
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n Press Enter to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }
```

My question is, how to convert this commands to send to server? I tried this:

```
Connect("192.168.0.250", "0");
Connect("192.168.0.250", "1");
Connect("192.168.0.250", "2");
```

But no server response.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure but try this:

```
        try
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(server, port);
             
            byte[] data = new byte[256];
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
             
            do
            {
                int bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                response.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
            }
            while (stream.DataAvailable); // while data in stream
         
            Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());

            // close stream
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("End...");
        Console.Read();
```

You can see my repo https://github.com/AkumaWalker/ClientServer with TCP chat
For work:

1. Build Client and Server console app
2. Open debug folder
3. Start Server.exe
4. Start Client.exe then input name and message => all clients and server will receive message

Comment: Hi Akuma.I tested your example, but it didn't work. The same thing happened as my example.. in the "Read" line always timeout. I need to send command to return data. All commands are in the "command" section of my post. I don't have access to the server, I only know there's a server, that I need to send command to receive data.

Comment: There may be a problem on your internet as some providers or network settings may interfere with connections (added video https://github.com/AkumaWalker/ClientServer/blob/master/2020-08-18%2017-57-25.mp4)

Comment: nah... the server is running on my local network. No internet issues or settings. I can connect.. but I can't read. Because I don't know how to send the correct command.